# What happens to your callsign if you migrate?

Tags: united-states, legal, callsign, germany

If, as an amateur radio operator, you're licensed in one country with a callsign,  let's suppose, the US and you migrate to, say, Germany, will you have to reapply and obtain a new callsign?

1. What if your migration is temporary, and you're only living there for a few years — can you continue using your old callsign?
2. What if it's permanent?

Comment: Every country has its own amateur radio regulations, so the answer may vary by country. Do you want an answer for a specific pair of countries you're considering, or one covering general principles? Please [edit] your question to clarify this.

Comment: Hi @KevinReidAG6YO, I'll clarify here instead because I think the question is clear enough. I was asking more in general and would've considered "your depends" as a valid answer as well since I had no idea if this were a country-by-country thing or an ITU thing regulated thing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have done exactly that.

I had a US amateur extra class license when I moved to Germany. As a legal resident of Germany, I applied for and received a reciprocal (no test required) German license with the call DJ0IQ. Yes, it was a requested/vanity call sign to match my US call. The good folks at [DARC](https://www.darc.de/home/) (the German equivalent to ARRL) helped me with that.

During the time I lived in Germany, I retained my US W9IQ license since the only requirement to do so was to have a valid US mailing address in my [FRN](https://apps.fcc.gov/coresWeb/simpleSearch.do) profile with the FCC. I could have retained my US license indefinitely this way.

When I would visit the US, the FCC regulations required me to use my US call sign. When I was travelling outside of Germany and the US, I could use the call sign most suitable to the situation.

When I moved back to the US several years later, I again updated my mailing address in my FRN profile and resumed operating with my US call.

While living in Germany, look up your local ham radio club - DARC maintains a list. It is a great way to meet local hams and get into local ham radio activities. The are also a number of ham radio swapfests in Germany. Check out your local ham radio dealer as well. I lived within 30 minutes from [WiMo](https://www.wimo.com/uebersicht-funkgeraete_d.html) so I was a regular in their store. They even casually offered me a position at one point because they needed someone with strong English skills to support their international growth.

A nice, technically oriented, monthly ham radio magazine in Germany is *[FUNKAMATEUR](https://www.funkamateur.de)*. You can pick it up in all book/magazine shops in Germany.

[image]

More generally, anyone that can pass an authorized US amateur radio license exam may hold a US amateur radio license. There is no requirement to be, to become, or to ever have been, a resident of the US. You must, however, have a valid US mailing address in your FRN. Many non-residents simply use the mailing address of a friend, a colleague, or a mail forwarding service. I knew several European hams that held US amateur radio licenses under these circumstances.

Comment: Ha same situation for me as well, and I also work just 3 bus stops away from WiMo. By the way, the callsign situation in Germany is a bit simpler now. There's a list of issues callsigns [here](https://ans.bundesnetzagentur.de/amateurfunk/rufzeichen.aspx), so it's possible to check if a callsign is free, and there's a spot in the application form for the license where you can put a list of the preferred callsigns. [Here](https://www.bundesnetzagentur.de/EN/Areas/Telecommunications/Companies/FrequencyManagement/AmateurRadio/amateurradio_node.html)'s a link to the forms in English.